# Delete or cancel app only with iTunes id

Tags: ios, xcode

1. Can i create app that the user can't delete without iTunes id or password?
2. Can i create app that the user can't cancel to background with home button without iTunes id or password?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No and No. The philosophy is that the user should always feel in control of their apps. You can only prevent app deletion on a device-by-device basis (using the device settings).